# How do I make the dropdown box appear underneath a tag?

Tags: html, css

When hovering the 'Drop' in the nav bar, I want the div to show underneath. However it doesn't show at all. When I do display it, it's at the top left corner. How can I make it so it will show underneath the Drop element, without hardcoding the values obviously.

This is some other text underneath the other text.

```css
/** @format */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: rgb(193, 235, 107);
}
nav {
    background-color: #333;
}
nav a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.drop:hover {
    background-color: rgb(193, 235, 107);
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.drop-content a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.drop-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
        <title>TESTING</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">News</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
            <a href="">About</a>
            <a href="">Something</a>
            <a class="drop" href="">Drop</a>
            <div class="drop-content">
                <a href="">Dropped</a>
                <a href="">Dropped</a>
            </div>
            <a href="">Last</a>
        </nav>
        <main></main>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m glad you could resolve your positioning issue. Also, using float is kind of outdated, you could simply use `display: flex` on the nav element. Beware that the current solution poses foundational issues for people with disabilities. Most importantly, it’s not keyboard usable. See [Disclosure Navigation Menu in the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html) for a great and solid example how to implement your pattern in an accessible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to wrap your links in an unordered list. Then wrap the dropdown within the same `li` as the main anchor to make the position relative to the element itself like the following:

### Note: You set `overflow` to `hidden` on all elements, you should remove that

```css
/** @format */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: rgb(193, 235, 107);
}
nav {
    background-color: #333;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.drop:hover {
    background-color: rgb(193, 235, 107);
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.drop-content a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.drop-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
        <title>TESTING</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="drop" href="">Drop</a>
              <div class="drop-content">
                  <a href="">Dropped</a>
                  <a href="">Dropped</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Last</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <main></main>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh I see the anchor point now. That makes sense. Now I get why its in the corner as well!